# getting mysql error: Invalid Function ErrorNr 1111

Tags: mysql, group-by

i was querying this in mysql, it was working before adding the line `COUNT(0)*COUNT(MAX(hdmhdrprice.dmduprice)) AS 'Total Quantity'`

After this line:

```
COUNT(MAX(hdmhdrprice.dmduprice)) AS 'Unit Value',
COUNT(0) AS 'On Hand per Count',
COUNT(0)*COUNT(MAX(hdmhdrprice.dmduprice)) AS 'Total Quantity'
```

I'm getting an ErrorNr. 1111

My whole query:

```
select concat(hgen.gendesc , ',' , (CASE WHEN hdmhdr.brandname IS NULL THEN '' ELSE CONCAT(' ' , hdmhdr.brandname) END) ,
                            (CASE WHEN hdmhdr.dmdnost IS NULL THEN '' ELSE CONCAT(' ' , CONVERT(hdmhdr.dmdnost,CHAR(14))) END) , 
                            (CASE WHEN hstre.stredesc IS NULL THEN '' ELSE hstre.stredesc END) ,
                            (CASE WHEN hform.formdesc IS NULL THEN '' ELSE CONCAT(' ' , hform.formdesc) END) ,
                            (CASE WHEN hroute.rtedesc IS NULL THEN '' ELSE CONCAT(' ' , hroute.rtedesc) END)) AS 'itemdesc',
              (case when hform.formdesc  IS NULL THEN '' ELSE CONCAT(' ' , hform.formdesc) END) AS 'Unit of Measurement',
              hdmhdr.dmdcomb AS 'Stock No:',
              COUNT(MAX(hdmhdrprice.dmduprice)) AS 'Unit Value',
              COUNT(0) AS 'On Hand per Count',
              COUNT(0)*COUNT(MAX(hdmhdrprice.dmduprice)) AS 'Total Quantity'

FROM    hdmhdr LEFT JOIN hroute ON hdmhdr.rtecode = hroute.rtecode LEFT JOIN hstre ON hdmhdr.strecode = hstre.strecode
                INNER JOIN hdruggrp ON hdruggrp.grpcode = hdmhdr.grpcode INNER JOIN hform ON hform.formcode = hdmhdr.formcode
                INNER JOIN hgen ON hgen.gencode = hdruggrp.gencode INNER JOIN hdmhdrprice ON  hdmhdrprice.dmdcomb = hdmhdr.dmdcomb

WHERE   hdmhdr.dmdcomb
GROUP BY itemdesc
```

The result would be something like this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gbh0e.png)

**Anyways, problem solved. Thanks for the support.**
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QUxLY.png)

Comment: Report the complete error message you are getting, not just the error no.

Comment: You are using nested  group by function  ..  count(max( ...  try explain your goal add  a proper data sample and the expected  result

Comment: WHERE     hdmhdr.dmdcomb - is this statement complete?

Comment: ERROR 1111 (HY000): Invalid use of group function - and does relate to the line added - what are you trying to achieve with this code?

Comment: it is getting an error message: "Invalid use of group function"

Comment: I added the line: COUNT(MAX(hdmhdrprice.dmduprice)) AS 'Unit Value',
              COUNT(0) AS 'On Hand per Count',
              COUNT(0)*COUNT(MAX(hdmhdrprice.dmduprice)) AS 'Total Quantity' to add a computed table

Comment: Both are invalid what are you trying to achieve with these 3 lines of code        COUNT(MAX(hdmhdrprice.dmduprice)) AS 'Unit Value',
       COUNT(0) AS 'On Hand per Count',
       COUNT(0)*COUNT(MAX(hdmhdrprice.dmduprice)) AS 'Total Quantity'

Comment: Itemdesc        |  Stock No: | Unit Value  | On Hand per Count | Total Quantity
Paracetamol   000254              50.00         user input/ 0              Unit Value*On hand

Comment: sorry can't create a table sample. the 3 lines would be to compute for the Unit Value table times the "On Hand per Count" equals to "Total Quantity"

Comment: The jargon you are using doesn't help what is COUNT(MAX(hdmhdrprice.dmduprice)) supposed to do? a max is a max what's the count for? A guess would be you want to count the number of items at the max price but I can't get my head around how that would be a unit value.

Comment: hahah problem solved..i  just removed the count  function..

Comment: already working now, my friend told me to use the count function so that it will count the items before the computation will work.. tsk